# $n$-couples of people in a row.

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

For the following problem, I feel my reasoning is something wrong, so I would like if it is in the right direction or if it needs to be rephrased/corrected.

The problem reads:

*How many ways are there to sit $n$ wife-husband couples in a row with no wife anywhere to the right of her husband if men and women alternate.*

The first step is to arrange either the men or the women in a row: $n!$.

Now I choose an arrangement, perhaps the easiest one and try to accomodate a women in each space (2 dots indicate an available space):

$$
..m_1..m_2.. (etc)..m_n
$$

Now, to the left of $m_1$ we can arrange any women. Now, suppose 2 cases:

(a) At first place, $w_1$ is not placed. Thus, to the right of $m_1$ there are $n-2$ options, to the right of $m_2$ there should be $n-2$ options, because here you can fit $w_1$.For this arrangement, at the end of the day there should be $(n-2)(n-1)!$.

(b) We place $w_1$ at the first place. to the left of $m_1$ there are $(n-1)$ options, to the right of $m_2$ $n-2$ options. Here we have $(n-1)!$ options to place the women.

(c) Here we choose to start the line with the men:

$$
m_1..m_2.. (etc)..m_n..
$$

To the right of $m_1$ there are $(n-1)$ options, then $(n-2)$, etc. Total here: $(n-1)!$

Answer:

$$
n! * ((n-2)*(n-1)! + (n-1)! + (n-1)!) = n!^2
$$

Last question: How this problem is different from the problem:

*How many ways are there to seat $n$ wife-husband couples in a row with no wife next to her husband on his right  if men and women alternate?*

To me, they both look the same.

Comment: Hi Brian. I think the arrangement you propose is not valid since we have to fulfill that men and women alternate.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that temporarily. Change it to $H_1W_2H_2W_1$: this gets counted for the second question but not for the first. Neither wife is immediately to the right of her husband, but $W_1$ is somewhere to the right of hers.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now the questions!

Comment: You’re welcome!